# Is there ever a reason to write "if (myBoolean == true)" in a JavaScript conditional?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, boolean, type-conversion

Many beginner programmers write things like `if (myBoolean == true)` as opposed to `if (myBoolean)` as they haven't yet grasped that conditionals don't need to contain a comparison, merely a boolean. When I noted this on twitter it was suggested to me that in JavaScript there  might be a good reason to do this. Is there? We all know JavaScript types are strange, but Google yields no answers on this specific point.

Update: It seems there is no difference, however there would be a difference with `if (myBoolean === true)`. So to clarify the question - what would be the best practice in JavaScript if (myBoolean === true) or if (myBoolean). In what real-world scenario would you be checking `=== true` to something that you don't know is a boolean? Please answer in this follow-up question: [Why is it good practice to use if (myBoolean === true) in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13250664/why-is-it-good-practice-to-use-if-myboolean-true-in-javascript)

Comment: In some cases it's helpful to call out the fact that you're explicitly relying on a boolean "flag" value being set to true. It's slightly clearer to write that out in full. Also, perhaps you meant `if (myBoolean === true)`? That is actually not equivalent to `if (myBoolean)`; it's only true if `myBoolean` is actually set to `true`, making it safer.

Comment: It's just personal preference. Now if you were talking about `myBoolean === true`, that'd be a different matter.

Comment: @Kiyura: *"It's slightly clearer to write that out in full."* I disagree, I find it makes it *less* clear. So this is clearly subjective and subject to personal preference. Agreed that `===` would be different.

Comment: Please see my update - I'm trying to work out why you'd ever be checking === true for a "truthy" value

Comment: @Iain: Please don't *change* your question. By all means clarify it, but don't *change* it. Your original question has been answered. If you want to ask another question (why would you use `===`), please do that *separately*.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder well I've done it now ;) The question I was getting at, is which is the best practice and why - which was always the intent of the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

Since you're using the [non-strict equality operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators), there is absolutely no difference between:

```
if (myBoolean == true)
```

And:

```
if (myBoolean)
```

There would be a difference if you were using the strict equality operator `===` and `myBoolean` was not actually a boolean, though.

Comment: To clarify, if `myBoolean` is not `true` but rather one of what Javascript calls "truthy values" like `5`, `'leeroy'`, or `{Some: 'object'}`, then `if (myBoolean)` and `if (myBoolean == true)` will both be true, while `if (myBoolean === true)` will be false. The former two will *coerce* the value to be a boolean; effectively the same as saying `!!myBoolean` or `new Boolean(myBoolean)`.

Comment: When would you ever need/want/end up checking something === true that isn't a Boolean?

Comment: @Iain, first of all, there's a distinction between a boolean value and a Boolean object; second, if you did `=== true` on something that won't have a boolean value, it would always be false. I'm not really sure what you're asking.

Comment: @lain, as an example, let's assume you write a function that takes a single argument, that argument being either the boolean `true` or an arbitrary string (this happens all the time in jQuery and jQuery UI). You would need the strict `===` operator to check if the argument is actually the boolean `true`, since non-empty strings also evaluate to `true` in a boolean context.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, In that particular case, it would probably be better to use `typeof`

Comment: @Kiyura, that's an alternative, yes. I don't know how "better" is is, though, it would probably depend on the conventions used in the code in question.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi thanks for your comment - your example of jQuery/UI is exactly the kind of case I'm interested in - could you give a specific example? I still don't understand how you can end up with either a string or boolean in a variable

Comment: @lain, see the [connectToSortable](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-connectToSortable) option, for instance (the boolean value is actually `false`, not `true`, but the same "boolean or string" pattern applies).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, You brought up jQuery and jQuery UI; Their code is *littered* with typeof (including checks for boolean), since they have such overloaded functions and objects. It actually is better to use that when you're checking for and/or handling a certain type. For instance, do you think it's clear and maintainable to assume you're given a boolean and blindly check a parameter for `=== true`, leaving the else-case for both `=== false` and the case where the input is in error? It's better to check `typeof var === 'boolean'` first, and jQuery agrees.

Comment: By the way, leaving aside the (marginally) subjective argument of clarity and maintainability, sometimes it's actually wrong to use anything but typeof. For example, there is no other way to safely check for `undefined`. In any case, it's better not to leave too much to Javascript's quirky duck typing to rectify.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a *real* boolean value (true/false) to be checked rather than just something with a truthy nature, you should never waste your time *comparing* it to true or false.

Your variables should be named in a boolean manner, like `isFinished` or `hasMoreRecords` so that statements can be read:

```
if (!finished) ...
if (moreRecordsLeft) ...
if (userHasLostTheirSanity) ...
```

and so on.

The problem with comparing booleans to true/false is that it just generates another boolean, and there's no definitive place to stop:

```
if (!((userIsMad == true) == true) = false) ...
```

Comment: This was totally my viewpoint - I just had a load of comments on twitter saying "yeah but javascript". So the question becomes, why in javascript would you end up needing to test "truthy" values that aren't true booleans.