# Why is it good practice to use if (myBoolean === true) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

As a follow-up to this question: [Is there ever a reason to write "if (myBoolean == true)" in a JavaScript conditional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13250176/is-there-ever-a-reason-to-write-if-myboolean-true-in-a-javascript-conditi) -

Why is it good practice to use if (myBoolean === true) in JavaScript? As a relatively inexperienced JavaScript user, I'm trying to work out in what specific, real-world scenarios you'd end up with a value that might be a Boolean true or might be a "truthy" value, so that you would need to check if (myBoolean === true) rather than if (myBoolean)

Comment: This is a question without any right answer, subjective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll challenge the premise of the question: I don't think it's good practice, nor do I think there's a general consensus that it is. :-)

The only reason for using `=== true` would be if you weren't sure that `myBoolean` was actually a boolean and you wanted the result to be false if it weren't. There are use cases for that, but they're quite limited. 99.9% of the time, simply `if (myBoolean)` suffices, even though it will be true for `1`, `"foo"`, and other truthy values.

There are times when using strict equality for other reasons is quite a good idea, because JavaScript's rules for loose equality if the operands are of different types are quite complex. But if you're using something as a flag, there's little if any point to using `===` on it.

---

One particular place where I've seen `===` used with boolean values is in code inspired by jQuery, where a callback function can cancel an action by returning `false`, but doesn't *have* to return anything. When a function has no explicit return value, the result of calling that function is `undefined`, which is, of course, falsey. So code that wants to check whether the function returned **`false`**, not just `undefined`, would do this:

```
if (callback(args) === false) {
    // The callback explicitly returned false (not just a falsey value), cancel
    // ...
}
```

But that's a *relatively* infrequent use case, and of course it involves `=== false` as opposed to `=== true`...

Comment: I generally only use strict equals `===` if I am comparing `null`, `0`, or sometimes `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Some random example:

```
function CreateSomeObject(param)
{
   if (param == "1")
   {
      return new Stuff();
   }

   return null;
}

var myBoolean = CreateSomeObject("1") || true;

if (myBoolean === true)
{
  //doesn't execute
}

if (myBoolean)
{
   //executes just fine
}
```

Comment: Why would you ever do that? myBoolean isn't even a Boolean here, it's an object that sometimes contains true...

Comment: For the sake of the example :) (it could be a boolean if that function returns null)

Comment: It definitely says in my question "real world scenarios", not hypothetical examples. Thanks for your help though :)

Comment: the pitfall here is protecting against some bad programming. The hole idea is that you never know what `var myBoolean` may hold. This can definitely can happen in "real world".

Answer (score 0):

In case of null only , you want to do that , although I never used this because it feels like more verbose and long string. No problem using it or avoiding it.It is more of style you want to write the code.

Comment: It is more than style, say a function returns a string or `false` to indicate something happened. if you only use `==` then you will get something weird when it returns `''` because `'' == false` is true. but `'' === false` is not. `'' == 0` also returns true which could cause problems if you are not aware of it.

Answer (score 0):

I constructed a slightly convoluted answer and then realised that the main reason is in the falsy values rather than the truthy ones. Usually, a function returns one kind of thing, and there is only one falsy value (the empty string for a string function, or 0 for a numeric one, or whatever).

However, when you aren't sure if something is defined or not, it can be instructive:

```
waitForResponse(request, 5000);
if(!request.ResponseValue) {
    alert('Server failed to respond');
}
```

vs

```
waitForResponse(request, 5000);
if(request.ResponseValue === 'false') {
    alert('Server says no');
}
```

Although I'd argue that you should check for undefined rather than boolyness:

```
if(typeof request.ResponseValue === 'undefined') {
   //...
}
```

Incidentally, `typeof` is fast, at least it was in Chrome last time I checked.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I don't like statements like *it's good practice to x*. IMO, it all depends on the context: if you want to check some object exists, `if(objectX)` will do just as `if (objectX === undefined)` or `if (typeof objectX === 'undefined')` and even `if (typeof objectX == 'undefined')`.

The reason why some people, like Douglas Crockford, strongly advocate the use of value and type checking (`===`) is that falsy and truthy values can, in rare cases, produce unexpected results:

```
var falsy = '';
if (falsy)
{//only when falsy is truthy, but an empty string is falsy
    console.log('could be seen as counter-intuitive: var was declared and assigned an empty string, but is falsy');
}
var obj = {falsy:''}
if (!obj.falsy)
{
   console.log('I might assume falsy is not set, although it was:');
   console.log(obj.hasOwnProperty('falsy'));//true
}
```

Again, this might just be my opinion, but in the vast majority of cases this won't break your code. I'd even go one step further: Douglas Crockford might claim that using checking for falsy values isn't a good idea, but he does like the logical OR (`||`) operator:

```
var falsy ='';
var someVar = falsy || 'default value';//this relies heavily on falsy values
```

The only *"solid"* arguments for strict comparison are:

- if you *need* the variable to be a boolean, but then again `falsy = !!falsy;` coerces to a boolean all the same
- strict comparisons are marginally faster, but you'll have to do a whole lot of comparisons before you'll be able to notice the difference

Having said that, I do tend to use strict comparisons an awful lot, again, it might be a personal thing, but I like to *know* what the actual type of a variable is:
Given that `'1' == 1` evaluates to true, but `'1' === 1` is false, it at least allows you to coerce a var to the type you need:

```
var foo = '00001';
var elements = [foo = ('00000' + (+(foo)+1)).substr(-5)];
while(elements[+(foo)-1])
{
    foo = ('00000' + (+(foo)+1)).substr(-5);
    elements.push(foo = ('00000' + (+(foo)+1)).substr(-5));
}
```

Now this isn't what you'd call *good code*, but there's a lot of type-juggling going on. At the end of the ride, you might want to know what value was assigned to `foo`. That's not an issue in this snippet, but suppose you want to use the numeric value of foo inside the while loop, if it's an odd number:

```
var foo = '00001';
var elements = [foo = ('00000' + (+(foo)+1)).substr(-5)];
while(elements[+(foo)-1])
{
    foo = ('00000' + (+(foo)+1)).substr(-5);
    elements.push(foo = ('00000' + (+(foo)+1)).substr(-5));
    if (+(foo)%2 === 1)
    {
        foo = +(foo);
        //do stuff with foo
    }
}
```

The easiest way to check weather or not `foo` is a string after the loop is completed is to check `foo` directly: `if (foo === +(foo))`
I am well aware that this example is a little far-fetched, but I have encountered a case quite similar to this one. It's at times like this where the advantages of strong-typed languages really show. speaking of which: `new Date() >= someDateObject` vs `Date() >= someDateObject`... try it in your console and you'll soon see what I'm on about.

Comment: Your first if statement is incorrect. That log will not be run because `''` is falsy so the if statement fails. The second one will succeed and run the log.

Comment: @Chad, You're right... that's what I wanted to make clear, but I didn't clarify what could be seen as counter-intuitive in that case, will edit my answer