# How do I make a bool to true once the condition is met and after the condition is met still stay true?

Tags: c#, boolean

I am trying to make a car driving script but the car should only move after `E` is pressed...

**Condition:** 
(Input.GetKey (KeyCode.E))

**What I have tried:**

```
    bool PersonInCar = false;
    PersonInCar=(Input.GetKey (KeyCode.E))||(PersonInCar==true)

    if (PersonInCar) {
```

Answer (score 4):

If (as per your title) your intent is to have the variable be true once your *condition* is true, and then remain true forevermore, you just need:

```
PersonInCar = PersonInCar || Input.GetKey (KeyCode.E));
```

The first time `Input.GetKey (KeyCode.E))` becomes true, `PersonInCar` will become true. Then no matter *what* value `Input.GetKey (KeyCode.E))` gives after that, `PersonInCar` will remain true.

You also need to ensure that you nexer explicitly change it back to false in some other manner, unless you need that for some reason. In other words, if you create it where you currently do, it will always be initialised there. You probably want to move it out of that scope (such as a member variable of a class initialised on construction).

You'll notice I've also changed your check against true - you should generally never compare Booleans with true or false sice they're *meant* to be read as a condition. See [Is there ever a reason to write "if (myBoolean == true)" in a JavaScript conditional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13250176/is-there-ever-a-reason-to-write-if-myboolean-true-in-a-javascript-conditi/13250319#13250319) for some more detail on that.

---

If instead (as per a possible interpretation of your comment) you want your car to move only *while* there's a person in it *and* the key is pressed, that's simply:

```
if PersonInCar && Input.GetKey (KeyCode.E)) {
    WhateverDrivingEntails();
}
```

Comment: This works only I have to hold E to move.

I declared the boolean with `bool PersonInCar = false`, after that I put
`PersonInCar = PersonInCar || Input.GetKey (KeyCode.E));`.

Comment: @Lucool, that's not quite what your question title indicates (the "still stay true" bit). On the off chance that you only want to drive *while* the E is pressed, I'll add to the answer.

Comment: @Lucool: if you need further help, I'd suggest clarifying what your actual intent is. As it stands, there appears to be some confusion as to what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

You are resetting the bool value to false (assuming PersonInCar is locally declared just before the condition).

Make PersonInCar to global scope (member of the class)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any variables here, in case you want you car always drive after E is pressed, use the following solution:

```
if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.E))
{
    Drive()
}
```

Besides, I would suggest to subscribe on press button events instead of using direct identifying of the key that was pressed.

Comment: This did not work for me... I tried it and the car just stopped doing everything. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

// first, register KeyDown event on form constructor or on form load

```
this.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(OnKeyDown);
```

now write a handler method to to handle the key press event.

```
private void OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{ 
 switch (e.KeyCode)
 {
    case Keys.E:
        DriveTheCar();
        break;

    case Keys.C: // It could be any key that end the application
        Application.Exit();
        break;
 }
}
```

and finally a method to drive the car.

```
private void DriveTheCar()
{
   if (PersonInCar) {
        // drive the car
   }
}
```

Comment: Why would you need `if(PersonInCar)` then? I mean, if we enter `DriveTheCar`, doesn't it mean that `PersonInCar` is `true` (*i.e.* the `E` key has been pressed)?

Comment: O! come on, that's just a condition that depends on the application. If application/game require person to be sited in the car (for a game, that I am considering this).  If does not require then no need.

Answer (score 0):

C# solution: You can use Linq. If PersonInCar is true it will ignore the rest.

```
bool PersonInCar = false;
PersonInCar = !PersonInCar? (PersonInCar || (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.E))): PersonInCar;
```